# R - Adding a flag in a new column only for rows of top/bottom ranks

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

(R beginner level, R studio on Win7)

I have a data-frame which I rank by state. I want to flag top rank as "best" and largest rank as "worst" but number of members for each subset differs so I have to calculate max index for each state and then update col "level". I can do it for "best" but can't manage to identify "worst" and I don't want to use loops:

```
mystate<- c(rep("TX",5),rep("AL",3),rep("NM",7))
mycounty<-c("TX1" ,"TX2", "TX3", "TX4", "TX5", "AL1", "AL2", "AL3", "NM1", "NM2", "NM3", "NM4", "NM5", "NM6", "NM7")
mycrime<-c(5,6,22,5,12,17,4,16,3,7,3,5,3,NA,16)
mydf<-data.frame(mystate,mycounty,mycrime)
mydf$rank<-NA
mydf <- transform(mydf,rank = ave(mycrime, mystate,FUN = function(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")))
mydf$level <- NA
mydf[mydf$rank==1,"level"]<-"best"
# flag worst next
```

results should look like this:

```
    mystate mycounty mycrime rank level
 1       TX      TX1       5    1  best
 2       TX      TX2       6    3  <NA>
 3       TX      TX3      22    5  worst
 4       TX      TX4       5    2  <NA>
 5       TX      TX5      12    4  <NA>
 6       AL      AL1      17    3  worst
 7       AL      AL2       4    1  best
 8       AL      AL3      16    2  <NA>
 9       NM      NM1       3    1  best
 10      NM      NM2       7    5  <NA>
 11      NM      NM3       3    2  <NA>
 12      NM      NM4       5    4  <NA>
 13      NM      NM5       3    3  <NA>
 14      NM      NM6      NA    7  <NA>
 15      NM      NM7      16    6  worst
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why no loops? Is this some sort of homework?

Comment: And what do you do if more than one county within a state has the same number of crimes?

Comment: I can split and do each state in a loop but want to learn a more efficient way.  ties.method='first' should take care of ties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**base R** Here's a way of getting "worst" and "best" both in one go:

```
mydf <- data.frame(mystate, mycounty, mycrime)

z = ave(mydf$mycrime, mydf$mystate, FUN = function(x) {
  r = rank(x, ties.method="first")
  factor(r, levels = range(r))
})

mydf$level = factor(z, labels = c("best", "worst"))
```

`ave` can't do the job on its own because it cannot return a `factor` (as far as I can tell).

---

**dplyr** and **data.table** analogues

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% group_by(mystate) %>% mutate(
  r     = rank(x, ties.method="first"),
  level = factor(r, levels = range(r), labels = c("best", "worst")),
  r     = NULL
)

# or...
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, level := {
  r = rank(x, ties.method="first")
  factor(r, levels = range(r), labels = c("best", "worst"))
}, by=mystate]
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) no packages** Use `ave` to compute a 0/1 vector which is 1 for the worst and 0 otherwise and then use `ifelse` to set the value of `level`:

```
is.max <- function(x) seq_along(x) == which.max(x)
worst <- with(mydf, ave(mycrime, mystate, FUN = is.max))
transform(mydf, level = ifelse(worst, "worst", level))

giving;

   mystate mycounty mycrime rank level
1       TX      TX1       5    1  best
2       TX      TX2       6    3  <NA>
3       TX      TX3      22    5 worst
4       TX      TX4       5    2  <NA>
5       TX      TX5      12    4  <NA>
6       AL      AL1      17    3 worst
7       AL      AL2       4    1  best
8       AL      AL3      16    2  <NA>
9       NM      NM1       3    1  best
10      NM      NM2       7    5  <NA>
11      NM      NM3       3    2  <NA>
12      NM      NM4       5    4  <NA>
13      NM      NM5       3    3  <NA>
14      NM      NM6      NA    7  <NA>
15      NM      NM7      16    6 worst
```

**2) dplyr** Using dplyr and `is.max` from above it could be done like this:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
     group_by(mystate) %>% 
     mutate(level = ifelse(is.max(mycrime), "worst", level)
```

**3) data.table**  Using data.table and `is.max` from above:

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- as.data.table(mydf)
mydt[, level := ifelse(is.max(mycrime), "worst", level), by = "mystate"]
```