# flag the 10 highest and 10 lowest values from a column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm looking for a command in r by which I can flag the 10(or n) highest and 10 lowest values. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33662513/r-adding-a-flag-in-a-new-column-only-for-rows-of-top-bottom-ranks) in which it does very similar to what I'm trying to do. The post suggests that `is.max` could do what I wanted, but I couldn't really find the command in R documentation.
Has it been updated to another command? Is there any other command in `tidyvese` or `dplyr` I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: `is.max` is the custom function defined in the first line of the answer `is.max <- function(x) seq_along(x) == which.max(x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

generate data:

```
set.seed(666)
rnorm(20) %>% as.data.frame() -> x

# choose breakpont (e.g. top10)
n <- 10 

x %>% arrange(x) %>% 
      mutate(rnum = row_number()) %>% 
      mutate(bottom_n = ifelse(rnum %in% seq(1, n), 1, 0)) %>% 
      mutate(top_n = ifelse(rnum %in% seq( n()-n+1, n()), 1, 0)) %>% 
      select(-rnum)
```

Here, we first order the values in ascending order, and create a helper column for row numbers. bottom_n=1 are rows that have their row number between 1 and n; top_n are the rows that have their row number between `n()-n+1` and `n()`, where `n()` is the length of the input vector.

Output:

```
             . bottom_n top_n
1  -2.21687445        1     0
2  -1.79224083        1     0
3  -1.77023084        1     0
4  -1.72015590        1     0
5  -1.30618526        1     0
6  -0.80251957        1     0
7  -0.58245269        1     0
8  -0.35513446        1     0
9  -0.07582656        1     0
10 -0.04203245        1     0
11  0.13412567        0     1
12  0.34490035        0     1
13  0.75331105        0     1
14  0.75839618        0     1
15  0.78617038        0     1
16  0.85830054        0     1
17  0.86465359        0     1
18  2.01435467        0     1
19  2.02816784        0     1
20  2.15004262        0     1
```